# Loops which repeat strings

Tags: r

I would like to write a loop which will help me to create a vector with strings. I have table with strings and number how many times each string should be repeated.

```
     Rival Elements
1    ORL    3
2    MIA    4
```

So my code should create a vector, v = ORL, ORL, ORL, MIA, MIA, MIA, MIA

```
i <- 1
while (i <= 1) {
xx <- c(rep(qwe$Rival[i], qwe$Elements[i]))
i<- i+1
print(xx)
}
```

and instead of these xx = ORL, ORL, ORL,  I received xx = 23,23,23. How to get string instead of these number?

Comment: Remove the `c()`, it is useless here.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it. `rep(qwe$Rival, qwe$Elements)` works perfectly for me.

Comment: You may want to ensure also that `qwe$Rival` is `string`, not `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
# Load your data
qwe <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Rival Elements
1    ORL    3
2    MIA    4 ")

#qwe$Rival <- as.character(qwe$Rival) # May or may not be needed
v <- with(qwe, rep(Rival, Elements))
print(v)
#[1] "ORL" "ORL" "ORL" "MIA" "MIA" "MIA" "MIA"
```

Make sure that `qwe$Rival` is a `character`.

Or do you want the following?

```
u <- paste(v, collapse = ", ")
print(u)
#[1] "ORL, ORL, ORL, MIA, MIA, MIA, MIA"
```

Which is a vector of length one with the element shown.

Answer (score 0):

At a first look your problem could be solved by using as.character().

Also you want <= 2 as R starts counting at 1, not 0.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Column "Rival" in your dataframe is obviously defined as factor. applying function c() to a factor, results in the numeric representation of the factor levels, see:

```
c(qwe$Rival)
```

in this case use as.vector() instead. However, like Pascal commented the c()-function is unnecessary in your code.

To get rid of the loop, you get your vectors by using

```
xx = mapply(rep, qwe$Rival, qwe$Elements)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it looks good. I need to spend more time on apply. Second question, how to do with xx vector because it looks like matrix right now and I need vector to add this as column to data.frame

Comment: It's a list, actually. You can access list elements with double square bracktes: xx[[1]] . But I don't get your question, you need this vector to add it to another dataframe? There are for sure easier ways to add extra columns to dataframes than this.

Comment: yep, this is  some kind of working frame. I have big table with players and I need to add rivals to every game, so I have 3 players who played against ORL and I need to add 3 rows with ORL, and after that 4 rows with MIA in this Rival column. 

Is there way to transform this list to see all elements as a one vector?

Comment: sure: unlist(xx). But I'd recommend reading [Hadleys' tidyr advises] (http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) maybe you can rearrange your dataframe in a way you can easily add new games.

Comment: hi @MarkusN, thanks for this link. I will look at this. I have question, still in this topic. I'm grabbing data from json and it looks ok when I assign value of this to y or other variable, but it is changing to factors when I try to rbind 2 variables

y  <- json_data$resultSets[[1]]$rowSet[1]
  x <- json_data$resultSets[[1]]$rowSet[2]
  x<- rbind(y,x)

as a result I have "Character, 16" instead of numbers or strings